# Core Data model organizing

Tags: core-data, model, relationship

I am trying to figure how to organize the model for following scenario: I want to add, change, delete prices for some stores. So, I suppose I will have the entity Store and Item.

Store attributes: name, address, city

Item attributes: eanCode, name

The problem is how and where to set price attribute?? As relationship (NSSet) in Item or self referencing in Item? In either cases, it seems that I will have problems fetching item prices from right stores. I am little confused. So, basically I need this:

```
Item:

ean

name

price set 

-> price 1 --> store 1

-> price 2 --> store 2
```

Store 1 and Store 2 are 2 records from Store entity.

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly you want each to Item to belong to some (or all) stroes and having price for each store it belongs to.

A Item have to belong at least to one store, a store  can have it (Item) or not. many store can have the same Item :(many to many) 
A item must have one price for each store it belongs to. 
A item can have multiple prices but only one price for a giving store.(one to many)

Store
attributes:
-name
-adress
relation:
-items
-prices

Item
att:
-name
relation:
-stores
-prices

Price
att:
-price
-lastChange
relation:
-ofItem
-inStore

I created a image for Model but it seems I need reputation to poste image...

1. create NSManagedObject-class for entities
2. create category (Create) on each class.

for the price be sure that the creation of instance must be with both item-instance and sotre-instance.

```
+(Price)createPriceWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)priceInfo  forItem:(Item*  ) item inStore: (Store*) store;
```

Comment: It is hard to read the relationships between entities just from text, please can you send me the image to velibor.santic@gmail.com? Thank you for your effort!